# copy Array values That Meet a Condition to another column excel vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to copy a set of values from an array than meet the condition (values < 70 for example) to the next column

```
'Qo reported (bd) - array
For i = 0 To cap
array_Qorep(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 1)
Cells(i + 1, 3) = array_Qorep(i, 0) 'copy array in the next column
If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Empty Then Exit For 'more values below, stop in blank
Next
```

the problem is that i don't know how to apply the condition i want in the array and then copying to the next column, is there a way to delete the values that doesn't meet the condition from the array and then copy them?

---

here is the solution for some reason it didnt work before but now it does :)
, and thanks Absinthe

```
'Qo reported (bd)

For i = 0 To cap
array_Qorep(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 1)
If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Empty Then Exit For
If array_Qorep(i, 0) > Cells(3, 4) Then
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = array_Qorep(i, 0)
    End If

Next
```

Comment: well this is a excel archive that my company uses, they update it and add more values, but they always put a blank space after those new values then some instructions, i want the code to detect the new values but then stop in the blank space they always leave, thats why its like that, the other failsafe i use it's the cap variable i can always change it so it loops more or less values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do it? Build your array first then:

```
arrPos  = 1

For x = 0 to myArray.length

     if myArray(x,0) < 70 then 
          cells(arrPos, 1) = myArray(x, 0)
          arrPos = arrPos + 1
     End If

next x
```

Comment: hmm that's weird i tried something like this before and it just spammed *true* in all the copied cells, but it worked i don't know why it didn't before, here is the final thing if someone its interested:

`For i = 0 To cap
array_Qorep(i, 0) = Range("A" & i + 1)
If Hoja1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Empty Then Exit For
If array_Qorep(i, 0) > Cells(3, 4) Then
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = array_Qorep(i, 0)
    End If

Next`

Comment: Can't really see what you're doing with Cells(3, 4) but glad it helped :)

Comment: that's where i add the condition using a *random* number (instead of just  using 70), cheers